# ifdef & make 3.81: invalid syntax in conditional

Tags: makefile, conditional-compilation

I have a makefile that used to work with make 3.80.
Now I updated to 3.81 and I obtain the following error:

```
Makefile:185: *** invalid syntax in conditional.  Stop.
```

Line 185 corresponds to:

```
ifdef $(FDEP_FILES)
```

A few lines above I define FDEP_FILES

```
FDEP_FILES   += $(addsuffix .df, $(TEST_BASENAMES_FC))
```

and

```
TEST_BASENAMES_FC      += $(basename  $(shell ls *.fc  2> /dev/null ))
```

The makefile works when there is only one .fc file in the folder, while it fails in case of multiple makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to is determine whether `FDEP_FILES` is defined then the test should be:

```
ifdef FDEP_FILES
```

The reason it fails when you have more than one file is that `$(FDEP_FILES)` will be expanded to its value and then `ifdef` will test whether the variable named with this value is defined. Since the value is not a valid variable name, you get an error.

But note that `ifdef` will consider a variable with an empty string as a value as being defined. With the code you've shown us, I'm not convinced that you won't end up with an empty string under some circumstances. You should consider testing with `ifneq ($(strip $(FDEP_FILES)),)`. With this test, the branch will be taken only if `FDEP_FILES` has a non-empty string as value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you thought the old version of make was doing, but it was not doing that.

The `ifdef` construct takes a *variable name* as an argument.  You are passing it a *variable value*.  If you have this:

```
FOO = bar

ifdef $(FOO)
```

then you're actually testing whether the make variable `bar` is defined or not.  If you want to know whether the make variable `FOO` is defined, you don't want to expand it:

```
ifdef FOO
```

In your situation you have a variable whose value has multiple words separated by spaces:

```
FOO = bar baz
```

In this case, in previous versions of make `ifdef $(FOO)` would not throw an error because make used to allow spaces in variable names, so make would check if the variable `bar baz` was defined or not--not what you wanted, but not a syntax error.

In the newer versions of GNU make, variable names cannot contain whitespace, so this:

```
ifdef bar baz
```

is now a syntax error.